# Как работают индексы в DirectX

Tags: c++, directx

Подскажите,пожалуйста, для чего нужны индексы и как они работают. На просторах интернета не нашел ответа

Например, у меня есть код вершин:

```
const Vertex vertices[] =
{
    { 0.0f,0.5f,255,0,0,0 },
    { 0.5f,-0.5f,0,255,0,0 },
    { -0.5f,-0.5f,0,0,255,0 },
    { -0.3f,0.3f,0,0,255,0 },
    { 0.3f,0.3f,0,0,255,0 },
    { 0.0f,-0.8f,0,0,255,0 },
};
```

А также индексы:

```
const unsigned short indices[] =
{
    0,1,2,
    0,2,3,
    0,4,1,
    2,1,5,
};
pContext->DrawIndexed((UINT)std::size(indices), 0u, 0u):
```

Как мне высчитывать эти индексы? Для чего они?

Comment: Указатели какую именено точку использовать как текущую вершину, индексы массива по сути. `0 -> { 0.0f,0.5f,255,0,0,0 }, 1 ->  { 0.5f,-0.5f,0,255,0,0 }, .....`

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо! Я почему-то думал, что это сами координаты относительно самой фигуры :)
Кстати, может подскажите хорошие туториалы для начинающих в DirectX (рус), где все хорошо описано? Я искал, но все они кончались на этапе самой разработки. Вроде бы нашел хороший канал на ют, но там на английском, не понимаю некоторые моменты из разговорной части

Comment: https://www.rastertek.com/tutindex.html

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/rendering-from-vertex-and-index-buffers

Comment: Моя любить OpenGL, просто индексы они и в африке индексы, и в DX индексы и даже в массивах.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Индексы нужны, если используются шейдеры вершин (Vertex shaders, VS) или шейдеры геометрии (Geometry shaders, GS), а если используются шейдеры "сетки" (Mesh shaders, MS), то индексы, как таковые не нужны! В них (MS) геометрия генерируется "на лету", внутри самого шейдера.